# How to set current date time in AWS RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS MySQL 5.7 instance and wanted to change the current date time ahead to do do some testing. How to do it? I could not find any option to configure it in the RDS parameter group.

Comment: Interesting use-case. My best guess is: you can't. I'm pretty sure MySQL takes the time from the operation system, and you won't have access to it with RDS.

Comment: _Why_ do you wish to do this?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I want test some code when day light saving occurs in US/Easter time zone. For that I am thinking of setting current time to 2 AM of march 8 2020 to test it.

Comment: A best-practice is to always store dates in a database with complete timezone information. Dates themselves are stored internally in UTC and timezone calculations are typically applied by SQL Clients. A daylight savings change should have zero impact on a database, but it can impact reports that are converting dates into local timezones for display purposes. It is not a good idea to store raw dates (with no timezone) as anything other than UTC, otherwise it leads to later problems when you need to deal with multiple timezones.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this. It is not a good idea to change the date/time on a computer running a database. This would cause the timestamps in log files to become incorrect.

All Amazon EC2 instances (and Amazon RDS runs on Amazon EC2 instances) are synchronized to a time server. The operating systems are configured to use UTC as the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You can set that using "`time_zone` parameter in the parameter group"

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.LocalTimeZone

Comment: Thanks for your help but using time_zone param you can't set the MySQL current date time howerver you want.